# How to setup cloud VPN tunnel using IPsec as third party?

Tags: meteor, cloud, vpn, galaxy

I'm using meteor and hosting my app on galaxy.meteor.com (Pro)

And I'm integrating with a third party that requires VPN tunnel configuration. Unfortunately galaxy only provide network customization for (Enterprise) containers, which is way out of our budget.

So my idea was to setup a cloud VPN as a third party router, and use it as follows

```
Galaxy <--(https)req--> VPN <--(tunnel)req--> Third party
```

Is this possible? and if so, how to do it?

Comment: Just to give you this note - this is not a meteor specific question but infrastructure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have to provide a meteor SERVER (backend) connection via VPN to the third party side? Something like a REST API?

So yes, you can do something like your request as suggested.

Checkout "HAPROXY" and / or "remote proxy configuration".

If you take the option of a small cloud server you may run OPNSENSE on that system and configure your HAPROXY and IPSEC tunnel via its web interface.

---

Update:

Here you get some links how to run AWS VPC (EC2) with Opnsense:

https://docs.opnsense.org/manual/how-tos/installaws.html

https://holdmybeersecurity.com/2017/09/18/setupconfigure-opnsense-router-in-aws-vpc/

Comment: Building off of Tom's answer. If you'd like to use some REST API within your meteor application be sure to check out webapp https://docs.meteor.com/packages/webapp.html

Comment: Stepping onto Harry's comment - this would allow you also to serve some REST API to the third party components thru the VPN tunnel. In that case you had to set up a bi-directional or reverse proxy configuration (absolutely possible with haproxy, too)

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I'm a developer, and having a real hard-time for "infrastructure" stuff. However, i'll scan these links and see what i can get out of it.

Comment: "holdmybeersecurity.com" guide is very thorough. I won't go through that hassle, it's not my fight, but i'll mark this as the accepted answer. Thanks